# Algorithm to identify contiguous repeated series of lines in a long string

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

I would like an algorithm that can identify repeated parts of big stack traces like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:700)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4754)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4801)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5586)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5603)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5723)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5731)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:714)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:700)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4754)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4801)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5586)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5603)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5723)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5731)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:714)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:700)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4754)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4801)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5586)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5603)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5723)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5731)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:714)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
```

With a bit of inspection, it's clear that this segment is being repeated three times:

```
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:700)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4754)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4801)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5586)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5603)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5723)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5731)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:714)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
```

The end goal is so I can print out stack traces of recursive functions in a nicer fashion

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
------------------------- Repeated 3x -------------------------
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:700)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4754)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4801)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5586)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5603)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5723)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5731)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:714)
at transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:789)
-------------------------------------------------------------
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5640)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInternal(Typers.scala:5672)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5613)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5618)
at typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4752)
```

I'm not sure how feasible this is, but I'd be happy for any and all possible solutions even if they have their own limitations and constraints. Preliminary Googling didn't find me anything, but quite likely I just don't know what to google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, JVM fills only the last 1024 calls in a stacktrace, and in Dotty/Scalac most stackoverflows have a repeating fragment of length ≈ 70 or less. A stacktrace T of a StackOverflowException can be decomposed into three parts S · R^N · P, where R is the repeating part of the stacktrace, S is some suffix of R, and P is either some prefix of R or an unrelated sequence of calls. We are interested in a solution such that the total length C = |S · R^N| of the repeating part and N are both maximal, and |S| is minimal.

```
// Scala Pseudocode (beware of for comprehensions)
//
// Stack is assumed to be in reverse order, 
// most recent stack frame is last.
val stack: Array[StackTraceElement]
val F: Int // Maximum size of R.

val candidates = for {
  // Enumerate all possible suffixes S.
  S <- ∀ prefix of stack
  if |S| < F
  
  // Remove the suffix from the stack,
  R <- ∀ non-empty prefix of stack.drop(|S|)
  // Find a fragment that ends with S.
  if R.endsWith(S)
  
  // Find out how many fragments fit into the stack.
  // (how many times we can remove R from the stack)
  N = coverSize(R, stack.drop(|S|))
  if N >= 2 // Or higher.
} yield (S, R, N)

// Best cover has maximum coverage, 
// minimum fragment length, 
// and minimum suffix length.
val bestCandidate = candidates.maxBy { (S, R, N) =>
  val C = |S| + |R| * N
  return (C, -|R|, -|S|)
}
```

The entire algorithm can be implemented in a way that does not allocate any memory (to handle OOM). It has complexity O(F^2 |T|), but exceptions are rare enough and this is a small constant (F << 1024, T = 1024).

I have implemented this exact algorithm in my library https://github.com/hobwekiva/tracehash (https://github.com/hobwekiva/tracehash/blob/master/src/main/java/tracehash/internal/SOCoverSolver.java) for the same purpose of simplifying scalac/dotc errors ;)

EDIT: Here is an implementation of the same algorithm in Python:

```
stack = list(reversed([3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]))
F = 6

results = []
for slen in range(0, F + 1):
    suffix, stack1 = stack[:slen], stack[slen:]
    
    for flen in range(1, F + 1):
        fragment = stack1[:flen]
        
        if fragment[flen - slen:] != suffix:
            continue
        
        stack2 = stack1[:]
        n = 0
        while stack2[:flen] == fragment:
            stack2 = stack2[flen:]
            n += 1
            
        if n >= 2: # A heuristic, might want to set it a bit higher.
            results.append((slen, flen, n))
        
def cost(t):
    s, r, n = t
    c = s + r * n
    return (c, -r, -s)
        
S, R, N = max(results, key=cost)
print('%s · %s^%d · %s' % (stack[:S], stack[S:S+R], N, stack[S+R*N:]))
# Prints [] · [2, 1]^4 · [2, 4, 3]
```

EDIT2: Following some of the ideas from mukel's answer, here is a function https://gist.github.com/hobwekiva/b041099eb5347d728e2dacd1e8caed8c that solves something along the lines of:

```
stack = a[1]^k[1] · a[2]^k[2] · ...
argmax (sum |a[i]| * k[i] where k[i] >= 2, 
        -sum |a[i]| where k[i] >= 2, 
        -sum |a[i]| where k[i] == 1)
```

It is greedy so it is not necessarily an optimal solution, but it seems to work reasonably well in simple cases, e.g. given

```
stack = list(reversed([
  3, 4, 2, 
  1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
  5, 
  4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
  3, 3, 3, 3]))
```

it produces an answer

```
[([3], 4), ([5, 4], 3), ([5], 1), ([2, 1], 4), ([2, 4, 3], 1)]
```

Comment: "The entire algorithm can be implemented in a way that does not allocate any memory." Do you mean that the algorithm can be implemented so that it only uses stack memory? Why is it useful to use stack memory only?

Comment: You might want to avoid allocating anything on the heap in case you catch an [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

Comment: I see. Well, it happens the error in the question is [StackOverflowError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

Answer (score 5):

Build suffix tree using [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ukkonen/SuffixT1withFigs.pdf), this way in $\mathcal O(n)$ you will find all substrings in provided text with indices.

In the case of approximate matching, there is also [extended version of Ukkonen's algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995885800462).

Answer (score 4):

If you consider that “a line of stacktrace” = “a character”, you can use:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem

One way to solve this problem efficiently is by constructing a Suffix Trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Every time you traverse an already estabilished path you are actually discovering a repetition in your string.

Now, simply list all the repetions in a separate data structure and extract the longest one... or all if you want.

Comment: The longest repeated substring problem appears to also find substrings which overlap, or are repeated with gaps between them. Is there a way to make it only find substrings which are repeated consecutively without gaps or overlap?

Comment: from the suffix tree, you can easily list all repeated substrings. 
I created the following Gist to show my idea: https://gist.github.com/nremond/fb63a27b6291053ca4dd1de81135de84
I'm a bit ashamed by the quick&dirty code, but if you like the algo, we can work on it.

Answer (score 4):

An efficient string factorization algorithm may help.
Given a string $S$, $n = |S|$ find maximum $p$ such that $S = T^p$ e.g. $T$ concatenated $p$ times, we call $T$ the **seed** and p the **period**. This can be done in $O(n)$ using the prefix function of the (Knuth-)Morris-Pratt algorithm, but don't be scared by the name it's very simple and beautiful algorithm, here's [my solution](https://github.com/mukel/ProgrammingContests/blob/3366b6a4447dd4df117217734880199e006db5b4/OldStuff/SPOJ/PERIOD.CPP) for the corresponding problem [SPOJ PERIOD](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PERIOD/).

Armed with a fast string factorization we can then proceed to decompose a string as the concatenation of factored chunks (dynamic programming) using a custom cost function e.g. minimize the total length of the seeds, minimize the sum of squares of the seeds' lengths...

$S = {T_1}^{p_1}{T_2}^{p_2}\cdots{T_k}^{p_k}$

Total complexity is $O(n^2)$.

If $O(n^2)$ is way too costly you can shift to a greedy like strategy e.g. as soon as you find a factorizable chunk, squeeze it and continue from that point, and also limit the maximum seed size (e.g. $|T|\le 200$) and prune the search if you don't find a period $\ge 2$ in the first e.g. 400 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
  string contiguous_repeated_string(string A){
    string r(1,A[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
      for(int l=2;l<=A.size();l++){
        string s=A.substr(i,l);
        if ((s+s).substr(1,2*s.size()-1).find(s)!=s.size()-1 and s.size()>r.size()){
          r=s;
        }
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
```

Call `contiguous_repeated_string("abcdefgabcdabcdabcd")` you will get `abcdabcdabcd`.

Call `contiguous_repeated_string("ATCGATCGA")` you will get `ATCGATCG`.

And then you can use KMP's `Longest Proper Prefix Postfix array` to fold the resulting string with `O(N)`.

Total time complexity is `O(N^2)`.

Comment: "Total time complexity is $O(N^2)$". What about the worst time complexity?